# PHP MySQL WAMP - Database Error

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

When I launch the website through local host, I get the following error:

**Database Error: Unknown database 'db_name'**

I'm having a dig around as to what the problem is. The website belongs to a friend of mine and he wants me to connect the website to the database. The database resides within the root directory. I'm merely trying to connect to it.

In most of the PHP files, there is a tag that includes the config file which contains the details of the database.

Any ideas as to how I can get it working and resolve the **Database Error: Unknown database 'db_name'** error?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Which website? Show us the part where you etablish the connection to the db.

Comment: What do you mean by the database resides in the root directory?

Comment: What do you mean the database resides in the root directory? MySQL is a database server, not a file.

Comment: If you are using PDO you need to specify the database name in the connection string. Are you sure that the database matches the name? Linux systems are case sensetive.

Comment: @Fluffeh somehow I severely doubt this code is using PDO...

Comment: Make sure you really have that database & you have the permission to access

Comment: @Michael So do I, but it has been so long since I used the mysql_* functions that I can't remember where the database name is used. I am just still stinging from having to case-correct an app which was migrated from windows to linux and had thousands of lines of SQL that was writen to be case-insensetive :(

Comment: @Fluffeh `mysql_select_db()`.

Comment: Mysql functions are being deprecated, I'd highly advise looking into PDO and restructuring your code now if you plan to use this in a production environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database should not reside in root directory, it should be imported to database (Mysql) server.

Check in Mysql databases, does your database resides there?
If not, you can do so by phpMyAdmin or navigating to your mysql and importing it.

Create database in mysql and import the sql file as below by opening command-line terminal:

`/path/to/mysql/bin > mysql -u username -p < /path/to/root/db.sql`